# Cannot add foreign key constraint in MySQL with FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, sql

I just created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_application` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `application_desc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `application_key` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_cotl49evfo7w4plf6213uaruc` (`application_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then I want to create this one:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_device` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_key` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `device_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `application_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `device_desc` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `application_id` (`application_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `t_device_app` FOREIGN KEY (`application_id`) REFERENCES `t_application` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

but its not possible because I got this error:

> **Cannot add foreign key constraint**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FK column has to have the same type as PK in referenced table:

> [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)
>
> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must
>   have similar data types. **The size and sign of integer types must be
>   the same.** The length of string types need not be the same. For
>   nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation
>   must be the same.

You have:  `int(11)` <> `int(11) unsigned`

```
CREATE TABLE `t_application` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `application_desc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `application_key` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_cotl49evfo7w4plf6213uaruc` (`application_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `t_device` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_key` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `device_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `application_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `device_desc` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `application_id` (`application_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `t_device_app` FOREIGN KEY (`application_id`) 
  REFERENCES `t_application` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a788)**</kbd>

So you can change: `t_application`.`id` to `int(11) unsigned`

or `t_device`.`application_id` to `int(11)`